# How to use DeflateStream on multiple chunks of data?

Tags: c#, compression, gzip, zlib, deflate

I implemented Websocket compression using a `DeflateStream` like this:

```
    public byte[] Compress(Stream input)
    {
        using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            input.CopyTo(compressor);
            compressor.Close();

            return compressStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

This works fine for the first message, however I need to keep the same compression context (LZ77 sliding window) and re-use it for the second message, instead of starting with new dictionaries each time.

My current workaround is to set the Websockets `client_no_context_takeover` and `server_no_context_takeover` option, to let the other side know that we're not recycling the deflate state.

So how can I change the above code so that it preserves the deflate 'state' for the next call?

Comment: can you read from the memorystream while it is still opened in the compressor, instead of converting it to an array?

Comment: @speising I think so. But the compressor doesn't flush anything to the memorystream until you call Close() it seems.

Comment: It is a micro-optimization that goes against all current proposals to add compression to WebSockets.  Mother of all bad ideas.

Comment: @HansPassant Chrome expects this kind of compression by default for 'permessage-deflate', Im just trying to follow their standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually read from the `MemoryStream` without closing the compressor:

```
input.CopyTo(compressor);
compressStream.Position = 0;
var mem2 = new BinaryReader(compressStream);
mem2.Read(buf, 0, 10000000);
```

will yield the contents of the `compressStream`. Just be careful to position to the end before the next write! (and of course, you have to keep your objects alive, as already noted).

Comment: This is not the case? I have tried this code and no bytes are available from the compressStream until the compressor has been closed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has implemented 'using' which disposes all objects when the method returns. As such you cannot maintain 'state' between different calls.

Try maintaining references to `compressor` and `compressStream` outside of the method.

Comment: I know, but that won't help in this case, since you have to call Close() on the DeflateStream before you can read the result, so keeping a reference at class level seemed pointless.